# Fscanf reads unmatching format from input

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read from a file only lines that respect this format : 
**identifier=any-char-string**, and ignore lines that do not correspond. Also i want to put **identifier** into a variable and **any-char-string** into another.

My code is: `if(fscanf(f,"%[^=]=%[^\n]",l.iden,l.string)==2)`.

For correct input like: "name=string" ,it works well but the problem is when I introduce unmatching input like : "i go home", it has no "=" sign but this line is interpreted as being correct . Any suggestions?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Im using C language

Comment: Add the according language as a tag not in the title or in comments.

Comment: Read _line_ with `fgets()` and then use `sscanf(f,"%[^=]=%[^\n]",...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put spaces in both sides of the equal sign. Otherwise it won't be able to distinguish the equal sign from the strings.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

    char identifier[100], any_char_str[100];

    while(1)
    {
        int ret_count = scanf("%s = %s", identifier, any_char_str);

        if(ret_count == EOF || ret_count == 0) // If it reaches to the EOF break the loop or if "scanf()" consumes nothing
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(ret_count != 2) // If exactly two strings are not found maintaining this %s = %s pattern ignore it (if more than one '=' is found like a = b = c it will take upto which the pattern is maintained)
        {
            continue;
        }

        printf("%s %s\n", identifier, any_char_str);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not quite right.  If scanf consumes nothing, it will return 0 and leave the file position unchanged, so each iteration of the loop tries to start reading from the same place.  Perhaps the argument can be made that the format string is such that this will never happen (indeed, I believe it is true in this case), but that seems incredibly fragile and this pattern will break if the scanf string starts with `%d`.  You should include a `ret_count == 0` case.  Also, with malformed input, this is not going to behave correctly w.r.t. line breaks.

Comment: @William Pursell thanks for your advice....I've fixed it. But I didn't get the corner case properly where it would fail...would you please consider to give such an example input?

Comment: Consider input like `"foo =\nbar = c\n"`